# How to Exit Method When Not for used this Method in Method

Tags: c#, login-script

```
protected void LoginCheck()
{
    if (Session["Login_Status"] == null || Session["Login_Status"] == "false")
    {
        MessageBoxShow("Please Login!");
    }
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoginCheck();
    Session.RemoveAll();
    Button1.PostBackUrl = "~/Default.aspx";
    Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
}
```

how to not process

```
    Session.RemoveAll();
    Button1.PostBackUrl = "~/Default.aspx";
    Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
```

when Login false

> how do I code this program not to use a
> condition if (LoginCheck()) { }.  I'd like it to work like
> php:
> [php exit; function](https://www.php.net/exit) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have `LoginCheck` return a boolean value indicating success or failure like this:

```
protected Boolean LoginCheck()
{
    if (Session["Login_Status"] == null || Session["Login_Status"] == "false")
    {
        MessageBoxShow("Please Login!");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then you can use that value to determine whether or not to do anything else like this:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (LoginCheck()) 
    {
        Session.RemoveAll();
        Button1.PostBackUrl = "~/Default.aspx";
        Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
    }
}
```

Comment: how codeing pro grame not use condition   if (LoginCheck()) { }
like php exit; function ?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand the question.

Comment: He wants his LoginCheck function to work like PHP's Exit function, which ends the request and stops execution and flushes the response.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want (but it's not that good of an idea):

```
protected void LoginCheck()
{
    if (Session["Login_Status"] == null || Session["Login_Status"] == "false")
    {
        MessageBoxShow("Please Login!");
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

Comment: Error 3 No overload for method 'End' takes '1' argument

Comment: I modified it.  There is an overload that tells it not to throw an exception, but I can't remember it offhand.  You can probably look into it if it's a problem

Comment: Here's a good tutorial: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8396/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-where-do-i-click

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad idea

If some one is reading your code, they are going to assume that after Logincheck() that Session.RemoveAll() ... will be called. If you do some trick in LoginCheck that changes that it will be very confusing reading Button_Click1(...)